# Reducing a double series into a single series

Tags: sequences-and-series

References told me that a double series can be reduced into a single series by change of indices. Consider $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n,m}$, by letting $m=p, n=p-q$, the series can be rewritten into $$\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \sum_{q=0}^{p} a_{p-q,q}$$ or,$$\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} \sum_{p=q}^{\infty} a_{p-q,q}$$ There also seems to be other possible substitutions, but what I basically want is an example in which a double series is reduced into a single one; it would be better if it uses the index substitutions above.

Answer (score 2):

I got a funny one where the sub actually works backwards.

Let $a_{n,m} = r^nr^m$

Then of course $$\sum\sum r^nr^m = \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}$$

But using the 1st sub above $$\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \sum_{q=0}^{p} a_{p-q,q} = \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \sum_{q=0}^{p} r^p =  \sum_{p=0}^{\infty} (p+1) r^p $$

So we can find the sum of arithmetic-geometric series this way.

Comment: Ok, so what happened is that the resulting expression for the partial sum is independent of the index of the inner summation after substitution?